# How to save my avocado tree

Tags: trees, avocado

[image: Avocado tree]

We planted it 2 months ago and it slowly started to turn brown. We would water it once a week. We live in a area where it does get hot under 100 degrees and is dry. Is there a way to save it?

Comment: A tropical plant getting adjusted needs more water than weekly. A quick test: snap off an inch of stem. If it snaps like a matchstick, it is dead wood and you caused no harm. Keep going. When you get to the bottom of the trunk, the whole tree is dead. Which it is. Uproot and take it back with tag & receipt to plead mercy.

Comment: Yeah, your plant is most likely dead.   You have the slimmest chance of saving it if you cut it near the base where its still green - but above a node -  but I would not rate your odds.